# Is it necessary to transmit predicted block of intra-prediction of H.264 or H.265 to decoder side?

Tags: h.264, h.265, video-compression, nalu

I am wondering is it necessary to transmit predicted block of intra-prediction of H.264 or H.265 to decoder side.

During intra-prediction, the encoder estimates all possible mode for given block size, retrieves predicted block according to picked mode and calculate residual block by subtracting predicted block and original pixel.

I am sure that residuals and the mode flag are necessary for the decoder, but not sure if predicted values are also required. It may be possible to get predicted values from the neighboring block with the mode flag.

Comment: _"But not sure if predicted values are also required"_ What problem(s) are you getting if you don't transmit them to the decoder side? That should explain if it is necessary or not.

Comment: I just have above questions when reading H.264/H.265 spec. Not facing any problem.